# merge multiple worksheets into one

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to merge multiple worksheets into one summary sheet.
Each Worksheet has the name 'Table #number', for example `Table 1`, `Table 2` etc. The layout of each sheet is identical. Data range is columns `A1 : N13`.
This function doesn't work: `=SUM('Table 1':'Table 25'!$A$1:$N$13)`.
How do I use `VBA` to amalgamate this data?

[image]

Comment: merging multiple worksheets into one has been covered many time in SO. Did you search SO? I would recommend searching SO and then trying it yourself and then post the code that you tried with the error message(i.e if any) and then we will take it from there? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub amalgamateData()

'initialise result variable
Dim myResult As Double
myResult = 0

'loop through sheets to get the sum
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet  'loop control variable
For Each wks In Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(wks.Name, 5) = "Table" Then ' only the "Table" sheets
        With wks
            Dim rngTarget As Range
            myResult = myResult + Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("A1:N13"))
        End With
    End If
Next

'add result to sheet "Result"
Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A1") = myResult

End Sub
```

My starting point was this [**SO Post**: how-to-merge-data-from-multiple-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806480/how-to-merge-data-from-multiple-sheets)

As Siddharth saud - there loads of references for you on SO [HERE IS A SEARCH FOR YOU ... CHECK OUT WHAT IS IN THE BOX IN THE TOP RIGHT OF THE SCREEN](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BExcel-VBA%5D+loop+through+worksheets+and+show+results+in+one+sheet)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MergeSheet()

'Declaring the Variables
Dim LastRow, ShtCnt As Integer
Dim ShtName As String
Dim NewSht As Worksheet

'Assinging a Sheet Name by UserInput
ShtName:
ShtName = InputBox("Enter the Sheet Name you want to create", "Merge Sheet", "Master Sheet")

'Count of Total Worksheet in the present workbook
ShtCnt = Sheets.Count

'Using For Loop check if the worksheet exists
For i = 1 To ShtCnt
If Sheets(i).Name = ShtName Then
MsgBox "Sheet already Exists", , "Merge Sheet"
GoTo ShtName
End If
Next i

'Create a New Sheet
Worksheets.Add.Name = ShtName

'Assigning NewSht as Current Sheet
Set NewSht = ActiveSheet

'Moving Worksheet to the beginning of this workbook
NewSht.Move before:=Worksheets(1)

'Copying all the data to the New Sheet Using For Loop
For i = 2 To ShtCnt + 1

'If i=2 Then copy all the data from the second sheet including header.
If i = 2 Then
Sheets(i).UsedRange.Copy NewSht.Cells(1, 1)
Else

'If i is grater than 2 then copy all the data excluding Header(1st Row).
Sheets(i).UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Sheets(i).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, Sheets(i).UsedRange.Columns.Count).Copy NewSht.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)
End If
LastRow = NewSht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Next i

'Displaying the Message after copying data successfully
MsgBox "Data has been copied to " & ShtName, , "Merge Sheet"

End Sub
```